# How can I crop everything outside of an art board in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, texture, artboard

I've got a very complex texture that I have running WAY over the art board and I need to clean it up for a client. How do I get rid of every point outside of the art board?

Comment: What kind of file are you delivering your client?

Answer (score 39):

I would make a rectangle the same size as the artboard and turn it into a *Clipping Mask*.

To do this:

1. Group together all the layers you wish to trim by selecting them and entering <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
2. Next, make a rectangle with the same dimensions as your artboard, and center horizontally and vertically.
3. With the rectangle layer in front, select both objects, enter <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>,

   - Or go to *Object → Clipping Mask → Make*.

And voilà. You will only see the parts within the dimensions of the rectangle. Simply double-click the new object to access the clipped information or enter <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> to get rid of the clipping mask.

Comment: thats perfect. but after doing that, how can i actually keep the resulting paths without the mask rect? i want to copy and paste in photoshop as a shape, but i get a black rect.

Comment: Does not cover all cases, indeed. I've tried exporting to wmf and found that the image still has the size of the bouding rect of the artwork.

Comment: What's the point of an artboard if not cropping everything outside it?

Comment: As a note, don't click the mask button on the layers pallet. That doesn't work, but command + 7 does (as stated in instructions lol)

Comment: One extra step to properly remove the outside bits, after the above, select it and then click 'Pathfinder > Trim'

Answer (score 11):

The clipping mask will not remove the paths and points that are off the artboard — it will simply hide them.

I would use the *Crop* pathfinder.

1. Create your artboard sized rectangle on top of the other objects
2. Select all the objects and *Crop* in the Pathfinder Panel. This will remove all vector objects that fall outside of the rectangle.

The resulting object will be a Group of paths — the top "cropping object" is still there — it will lose it's fill and stroke — but if you need them then you simply reapply fill or stroke.

This will not work on bitmap images or type that not been expanded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in photoshop id save it in GIF or PNG since wokking paths wont be useful in photoshop anyway and this will corp everything beyond an artboard off + preserve transparency.